# Cartesian to spherical coordinates translation - how to differentiate x/y signs

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I am using [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations) translation formulae when writing my Cartesian2sherical function (sorry I don't have enough reputaton to post in-line image, but here is the link, and I will rewrite it too):
[link_to_wiki_formulae_image](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/613188b63c9f2e1d9717df2f1f92cd3f8a3fdb42)

$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 +z^2}$$
$$\theta = \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{z})$$
$$\phi = \arctan(\frac{y}{x}) =\arccos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) = \arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})$$

However, the above formulae do not handle the case where x or y is negative: the first two formulae squares x and y so the signs do not matter. Formula 3 falls apart when x or y are negative. For example, when x = -1 and y = -1, the 3 equalities in equation 3 don't even hold:

$$\arctan(\frac{y}{x}) = \arctan(1) = 0.7853982$$
$$\arccos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) = \arccos(-0.7071068) = 2.356194$$
$$\arcsin(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}) = \arcsin(-0.7071068) = -0.7853982$$

Does that mean the Wikipedia formulation is lacking some pre-assumptions of the x and y value? What would I change the formulae if I wanted to handel the case where x and y could have arbitrary signs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the link from that page to the main article on spherical coordinates, in particular, to the [Cartesian Coordinates section](http://If%20you%20follow%20the%20link%20from%20that%20page%20to%20the%20main%20article%20on%20spherical%20coordinates,%20in%20particular,%20to%20the%20[Cartesian%20Coordinates%20section%20of%20that%20article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates)) of that article, you will find the following caveat:

> The inverse tangent denoted in $\varphi = \arctan\frac yx$ must be
>   suitably defined, taking into account the correct quadrant of $(x,y)$.

This is a common gotcha when working with the inverse tangent function as part of a coordinate transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I also found in R, I could use `atan2(y,x)` instead of `atan(y/x)` that'd solve the practical part of the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse trig functions are multivalued. You just have to decide in which quadrant you want the answer.

Notice that $2.35619-\pi=-0.78539$